# Get struct socket*, struct sock * from socket descriptor in a C program on Linux

Tags: c, linux, sockets, tcp, ip

I'm working on a C program on Linux (unprivileged).

Is it possible to get a reference to `struct socket` or `struct sock` from the socket descriptor?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're working in user mode (eg. not kernel mode), you cannot directly manipulate kernel structures (including `struct sock`). If you do need access to these kernel structures, you will need to write code running in kernel mode (likely in a kernel module).

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at sockfd_lookup_light function (http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/net/socket.c#L449), that's how system does that.

Comment: I think, it should be `sockfd_lookup`. `sockfd_lookup_light` is marked as static, Hence can not call from outside of the file

Comment: Thank you guys, I actually got there but with no success. The problem is that sockfd_lookup() is not present in`/usr/include/linux/net.h` but it is present in `/usr/src/linux-headers-VERSION/include/linux/net.h`.

Comment: Can I compile with `gcc` using those headers and will the resulting binaries run in unprivileged mode?